# Split window in vim to browse files, then open file in original window

Tags: vim

I've tried out the NERDTree plugin for vim, and it's very powerful but is probably overkill for what I use it for. I'm not anti-plugin in general, but I don't like relying on plugins when I'm not using them to their full extent.

What I'm really looking for is the ability to open the file browser in a split, similar to how `:Sex` and `:Vex` work. I'd select the file I want, which would open in the original window, and the file browser goes away.

Are there any built-in commands that would work this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See `:help netrw` for all the mappings available in `:Ex` and friends.

The one you want is simply `P`.

By the way, netrw is also a plugin.

Comment: Excellent, perfect. I haven't quite gotten my head around the netrw help yet. And yeah, it's a plugin too, but it ships with vim, or at least every instance of vim I've tried.

Comment: It has been everywhere for me as well. I don't know if it ships with every version: maybe not in "tiny" but it's there in "normal" and up, at least.